# Problemas para gerar o JSON com JAVA

Tags: java, json, loop, foreach, lógica

Estou com problemas para gerar este json

```
{
    "receita": [{
        "specialtys": [{
            "date": "27/01/2016 00:00:00",
            "itemSpecialtys": [{
                "specialtyId": 1,
                "specialtyName": "Tabelionato de Notas",
                "receitas": [{
                    "id": 2,
                    "date": "27/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "Escrituras - Lavratura de escrituras públicas com valor declarado (15) - Teste Receita Joyce -",
                    "value": 20
                }, {
                    "id": 3,
                    "date": "27/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "Escrituras - Lavratura de escrituras públicas com valor declarado (15) - Joyce",
                    "value": 200
                }, {
                    "id": 4,
                    "date": "27/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "Escrituras - Lavratura de escrituras públicas com valor declarado -",
                    "value": 3
                }, {
                    "id": 5,
                    "date": "27/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "Escrituras - Lavratura de escrituras públicas com valor declarado - teste",
                    "value": 300
                }, {
                    "id": 7,
                    "date": "27/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "Escrituras - Lavratu- teste teste teste",
                    "value": 3
                }, {
                    "id": 9,
                    "date": "27/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "Escrituras - Lavratura de escrituras públicas com valor declarado -",
                    "value": 0.33
                }, {
                    "id": 10,
                    "date": "27/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "eem valor declarado -Escrituras - Lavratura de escrituras declarado -",
                    "value": 0.33
                }, {
                    "id": 11,
                    "date": "27/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "Reconhecimento de firmas - Reconhecimento de firma -",
                    "value": 3.33
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "date": "26/01/2016 00:00:00",
            "itemSpecialtys": [{
                "specialtyId": 1,
                "specialtyName": "Tabelionato de Notas",
                "receitas": [{
                    "id": 6,
                    "date": "26/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "Escrituras - ",
                    "value": 20
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "date": "01/01/2016 00:00:00",
            "itemSpecialtys": [{
                "specialtyId": 1,
                "specialtyName": "Tabelionato de Notas",
                "receitas": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "date": "01/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "outro teste ",
                    "value": 20
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "date": "28/01/2016 00:00:00",
            "itemSpecialtys": [{
                "specialtyId": 1,
                "specialtyName": "Tabelionato de Notas",
                "receitas": [{
                    "id": 8,
                    "date": "01/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "outro teste ",
                    "value": 20
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

pois o que eu to obtendo de resposta das minhas funções é isso:

```
{
    "receita": [{
        "specialtys": [{
            "date": "27/01/2016 00:00:00",
            "itemSpecialtys": [{
                "specialtyId": 1,
                "specialtyName": "Tabelionato de Notas",
                "receitas": [{
                    "id": 2,
                    "date": "27/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "Escrituras - Lavratura de escrituras públicas com valor declarado (15) - Teste Receita Joyce -",
                    "value": 20
                }, {
                    "id": 3,
                    "date": "27/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "Escrituras - Lavratura de escrituras públicas com valor declarado (15) - Joyce",
                    "value": 200
                }, {
                    "id": 4,
                    "date": "27/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "Escrituras - Lavratura de escrituras públicas com valor declarado -",
                    "value": 3
                }, {
                    "id": 5,
                    "date": "27/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "Escrituras - Lavratura de escrituras públicas com valor declarado - teste",
                    "value": 300
                }, {
                    "id": 7,
                    "date": "27/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "Escrituras - Lavratu- teste teste teste",
                    "value": 3
                }, {
                    "id": 9,
                    "date": "27/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "Escrituras - Lavratura de escrituras públicas com valor declarado -",
                    "value": 0.33
                }, {
                    "id": 10,
                    "date": "27/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "eem valor declarado -Escrituras - Lavratura de escrituras declarado -",
                    "value": 0.33
                }, {
                    "id": 11,
                    "date": "27/01/2016 00:00:00",
                    "descricao": "Reconhecimento de firmas - Reconhecimento de firma -",
                    "value": 3.33
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "date": "26/01/2016 00:00:00"
        }, {
            "date": "01/01/2016 00:00:00"
        }, {
            "date": "28/01/2016 00:00:00"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Repare que ele monta a primeira divisao por data corretamente, mas nao
replica para as outras datas, ou seja, ele nao repete o loop, alguem
saberia qual o erro de LOGICA que estou cometendo? os metodos que
estou utilizando são esses:

```
private List<RelatorioTO> orderSpecialtyListForDate(List<ReceitaTO> receitasTO){
    List<RelatorioTO> relatorioTOs = new ArrayList<RelatorioTO>();
    List<RelatorioEspecialidadeTO> specialtys = new ArrayList<RelatorioEspecialidadeTO>();
    List<ReceitaTO> receitasOK = new ArrayList<ReceitaTO>();
    //verifica cada receita pra comparar e ornaginar por data
    Boolean exists = false;
    for (ReceitaTO rTO : receitasTO){
        exists = false;
        for(RelatorioEspecialidadeTO specialty : specialtys){ // acho que ta aqui o problema
            if(rTO.getEffectuationDate().equals(specialty.getDate())){
                receitasOK.add(rTO);
                //verifica cada receita pra comparar e ornaginar por especialidade
                specialty.setValues(orderItemSpecialtyListForSpecialty(specialty, receitasOK));
                exists = true;
            }
        }
        if(!exists){
            RelatorioEspecialidadeTO specialty = new RelatorioEspecialidadeTO();
            specialty.setDate(rTO.getEffectuationDate());
            specialtys.add(specialty);
        }
    }

    RelatorioTO relTO = new RelatorioTO();
    relTO.setSpecialty(specialtys);
    relatorioTOs.add(relTO);
    return relatorioTOs;
}


private List<RelatorioItemEspecialidadeTO> orderItemSpecialtyListForSpecialty(RelatorioEspecialidadeTO specialty, List<ReceitaTO> receitasOK){
    List<RelatorioItemEspecialidadeTO> specialtys = new ArrayList<RelatorioItemEspecialidadeTO>();
    //verifica cada receita pra comparar e ornaginar po especialidade
    Boolean exists = false; 
    for (ReceitaTO rTO : receitasOK){
        exists = false;
        if(specialtys.size() == 0) {
            RelatorioItemEspecialidadeTO itemSpecialty = new RelatorioItemEspecialidadeTO();
            itemSpecialty.setSpecialtyId(rTO.getSpecialty().getIdSpecialty());
            itemSpecialty.setSpecialtyName(rTO.getSpecialty().getDescription());
            specialtys.add(itemSpecialty);
        }
        for(RelatorioItemEspecialidadeTO itemSpecialty : specialtys){
            if(rTO.getSpecialty().getIdSpecialty().equals(itemSpecialty.getSpecialtyId())){                         
                //verifica cada receita pra comparar e ornaginar por id
                itemSpecialty.setReceitas(orderRevenuesListbyID(receitasOK));
                exists = true;
            }
        } 
        if(!exists) {
            RelatorioItemEspecialidadeTO itemSpecialty = new RelatorioItemEspecialidadeTO();
            itemSpecialty.setSpecialtyId(rTO.getSpecialty().getIdSpecialty());
            itemSpecialty.setSpecialtyName(rTO.getSpecialty().getDescription());
            specialtys.add(itemSpecialty);
        }
    }
    return specialtys;
}

private List<RelatorioReceitasTO> orderRevenuesListbyID(List<ReceitaTO> receitasTO) {
    List<RelatorioReceitasTO> receitas = new ArrayList<RelatorioReceitasTO>();
    //verifica cada receita pra comparar e ornaginar po especialidade
    for (ReceitaTO rTO : receitasTO){
        Boolean exists = false;         
        for(RelatorioReceitasTO receita : receitas){
            if(rTO.getIdRevenue().equals(receita.getId())){                         
                exists = true;
            }
        }
        if(!exists){
            RelatorioReceitasTO receita = new RelatorioReceitasTO();
            receita.setId(rTO.getIdRevenue());
            receita.setDate(rTO.getEffectuationDate());
            receita.setDescricao(rTO.getDescription());
            receita.setValue(rTO.getValue());
            receitas.add(receita);
        }
    }
    return receitas;
}
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: ainda nao cara =S

Comment: Já verificou se a lista que tu estás recebendo contém os carinhas que tu desejas referenciar? Se puderes, posta o código onde é preenchida essa lista.

Comment: sim estou conseguindo montar e acessar os dados, o problema é de logica, ele monta  uma parte apenas uma vez, apesar de criar a separação das datas

Comment: Amigo, para poder tentar lhe ajudar, preciso de mais informações. Podes postar todo o fluxo de construção do JSON?

Comment: Tá usando o que pra serializar o JSON? Como estão seus objetos (os seus TOs)? Não deve ser problema ao preencher seus objetos, mas alguma *back reference* configurada errada, como os dados são iguais, alguns serializers não duplicam a informação por padrão.

Comment: Você tá serializando o json na mão?? Sugiro que você use apis que fazem isso pra você, como essa: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.2.3.